# How do I check the progress of a reindex command in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently running a reindex table command on one of my Postgres 8.3 databases.  Unfortunately the command doesn't really tell you anything until it is done.

Is there any way to check the progress of this command?  Maybe a system table I could read some useful stats out of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not really. Your best option is probably to check the size of the file in the data directory, and compare it to whatever the old file has. (The old file won't be removed until the transaction that creates the new one has committed)